# Run time error with AssociatedType, Generics and Inheritance

Tags: swift, generics, inheritance, swift2, associated-types

## Why the following code breaks at run-time (EXC_BAD_ACCESS)?

```
public protocol P1 {
    associatedtype Cell

    var p1 : Array<Cell>? {get set}
}

public struct P1Struct<Cell> : P1 {
    public var p1 : Array<Cell>?
}

public class Class1<T : P1> : NSObject {
    public var d1 : T?

    public required override init() {
        super.init()
    }
}

public class Class2<X>: Class1<P1Struct<X>> {
    let headerIdentifier2 = "HeaderViewIdentifier"

    public required init() {
        super.init()
    }
}

let c1 = Class1<P1Struct<Int>>() // OK
let c2 = Class2<Int>() // EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

---

## Extra info

After some debugging, I've discovered that if you remove (or move it to Class1) the following line:

```
    let headerIdentifier2 = "HeaderViewIdentifier"
```

The code works at run-time. But I still don't understand why. Am I missing something? I'm using XCode Version 7.3 (7D175), Swift 2.2

Maybe it is related to the use of NSObject, nested generics, this generics inheritance hierarchy or all of them mixed together.